# MYSQL - Filter consecutive not null dates

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Get only the biggest date:
[image: Get only the biggest date]

These are check-in and check-out records of employees, some times they do twice or more entries on the system in a row. In this sample there were two check-out in a row. Assuming these rows always gonna be ordered, in the case of check-out I would like have the biggest date, and in the case of the check-in the smallest date.

In that case I would like to have this:

The smaller date was excluded:
[image: The smaller date was excluded]

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8cb6424)

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: I am using version 5.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, in this big `CASE` statement I increment column by one, if `checkin` switches from `null` to `not null` and the other way around. Then it's enough to group by this column taking `max` and `min` of `checkout` and `checkin` respectively:

```
select @checkinLag := null, @rn := 0;
select max(id), 
       functionario,
       loja, 
       min(checkin),
       max(checkout) 
from (
    select case when (checkinLag is null and checkin is not null) or
                     (checkinLag is not null and checkin is null)
                then @rn := @rn + 1 else @rn end rn,
           checkin,
           checkout,
           loja,
           id,
           functionario           
    from (
        select @checkinLag checkinLag,
               @checkinLag := checkin,
               checkin,
               checkout,
               loja,
               id,
               functionario
        from dummyTable
        order by coalesce(checkin, checkout)
    ) a
) a group by functionario, loja, rn
```

I have used subqueries, to guarantee order of evaluating expressions (assigning and using of `@checkinLag`), as Gordon Linoff pointed.

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8cb6424/17)

Comment: This is not guaranteed to work, because you are using the value of `@checkinLag` and setting it in two separate expressions.  MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions.

Comment: @GordonLinoff You're right, I forgot about `order by`. Updated answer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I get your point now. I used subqueries to guarantee the order of expressions.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
Select
  *
from dummyTable base
where (base.checkout is null or not exists (
  select
    1
  from dummyTable co
  where co.checkout between base.checkout and DATE_ADD(base.checkout, INTERVAL 5 SECOND)
  and base.id <> co.id
  and base.functionario = co.functionario
  and base.loja = co.loja
)) and (base.checkin is null or not exists (
  select
    1
  from dummyTable ci
  where ci.checkin between DATE_SUB(base.checkin, INTERVAL 5 SECOND) and base.checkin
  and base.id <> ci.id
  and base.functionario = ci.functionario
  and base.loja = ci.loja
));
```

you can test the query [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8cb6424/4/0). There is no need that the rows are orderd. I choose 5 seconds as the interval where check-in/outs should be ignored.